# ¿Cómo enviar un PDF generado por un RDLC adjunto a un correo?

Tags: c#

Hasta el momento ya he conseguido generar el PDF con un RDLC y enviar mail con la liberia MailMessage pero lo que me falta es el como adjuntar este PDF generado al envio del correo.

#### Generar PDF

```
ReportDataSource reporte = new ReportDataSource();
reporte.Name = "FLASHREPORTS";
reporte.Value = new ConsultaDAL().Obtener_FlashReport(iCodigoAtencion, vcCodigoSede);
```

#### Enviar Correo

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add(Correo);
mail.From = new MailAddress("correo_prueba@servidor.dominio");
mail.Subject = Asunto;
mail.Body = CuerpoMensaje;
mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtp.servidor";
smtp.Credentials = new 
System.Net.NetworkCredential("correo_prueba@servidor.dominio", "******");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes añadir este código, reemplazando la ruta "**C:/RutaDelPDF.pdf**" por la ruta en donde guardaste tu PDF.

```
  System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
  attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("c:/RutaDelPDF.pdf");
  mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví del siguiente modo:

```
var viewer = new LocalReport();
ReportDataSource reporte = new ReportDataSource();
reporte.Name = "FLASHREPORTS";
reporte.Value = new ConsultaDAL().Obtener_FlashReport(iCodigoAtencion, vcCodigoSede);
```

Cargo el reporte y genero el arreglo de bytes:

```
viewer.DataSources.Add(reporte);
viewer.Refresh();
byte[] bytes = viewer.Render("PDF");
```

Creo el objeto de la liberia mail

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add(Correo);
mail.From = new MailAddress("correo_prueba@servidor.dominio");
mail.Subject = Asunto;
mail.Body = CuerpoMensaje;
mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Llamo al método de la librería Mail **Attachments**

```
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), "" + nombrePDF  + "-" + vcCodigoSede + ".pdf"));
```

Al final se envía :D

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtp.servidor";
smtp.Credentials = new 
System.Net.NetworkCredential("correo_prueba@servidor.dominio", "******");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(mail);
```